# Work out components $F^{01}$ and $F^{ij}$ of the antisymmetric tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ under the Lorentz Transform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, symmetry, tensor-calculus

> Work out explicitly how the components $F^{0i}$ and $F^{ij}$ of the antysymmetric tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ introduced in chapter I.6 transform under a Lorentz transformation

This problem is from Zee, Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell.
Things that I've gathered through many pages of readings that will pertain to this problem:

Here $0i$ must be the time components of $F$ and $ij$ must be the spacial components of $F$.

- Define a (2,0) tensor $T^{\mu\nu} \rightarrow \Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\sigma}\Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\omega}T^{\sigma\omega}.$

The Lorentz Transformation is $${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu = \begin{pmatrix}\gamma & -\beta \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ -\beta \gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

- An antisymmetric matrix must have zeros on its diagonal. The general 3x3 antisymmetric matrix is of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ -a_{12} & 0 & a_{23} \\ -a_{13} & -a_{23} & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

All the book mentions in section I.6 is the following:

> Let's count. We are in $D$-dimensional space. First, note that the number of independent elements in an antisymmetric $D$-by-$D$ matrix $F_{\mu\nu} = - F_{\mu\nu}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}D(D-1)$, since, for each of the $D$ values the first index can take on, the second index can take only $D-1$ values. In contrast, a symmetric $D$-by-$D$ matrix has $\frac{1}{2}D(D+1)$ elements.

But anyways, what should I do next? Is this information at all helpful? I got some of these pictures from different resources so I'm not sure how relevant they are to each other.

oh and also the book didn't bring it up explicitly (and I haven't taken an electrodynamics course at all yet) but in some of the articles I've read sometimes they denote $F^{\mu\nu}$  to have something to do with the Electro-magnetic force (also called the Lorentz force right? I.e. the sum of electric and magnetic force?).

Comment: This looks really close to what the problem is asking: http://www.physicspages.com/2013/03/26/electromagnetic-field-tensor-lorentz-transformations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see how the components of the electromagnetic tensor transform from $F$ to $F'$ under a Lorentz transformation you take the  [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor)
$$F^{\mu \nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -E_x /c & -E_y /c & - E_z /c\\
E_x /c & 0 & -B_z & B_y\\
E_y /c & B_z & 0 & -B_x\\
E_z /c & -B_y & B_x & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

and apply the Lorent-transformation by the form you gave $F'=F^{\alpha\beta}=\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\mu}\Lambda^{\beta}_{\,\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ where you have to multiply the matrices in the following way: $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\mu} * F^{\mu\nu}* \Lambda^{\beta}_{\,\nu}$. In the new matrix you will read the components $\alpha\beta$ as the transformed ones from $\mu\nu$.

Note that your given Lorentztranformation is only valid for [Boost in x-direction with velocity v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation). But since the boost direction is not specified in the question it is probably the right one.